# Centering a page

Tags: css, html

I have an issue with my page centering. Everything centers correctly except the left and right border.I believe the issue is with the `border-right-width:300px; border-left-width:300px;` lines but I am not sure of another way to set that up. Is there another solutuion to having a left and right border that also centers with the page. Any ideas?
Here is my CSS:

```
body {    
    margin:auto;
    padding: 0;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    font: 12px/1.4 Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000000;
    border-right-style:solid;
    border-left-style:solid;
    border-right-width:300px;
    border-left-width:300px;
    border-color:#E8E8E8;
}
```

Comment: 300 Pixel BORDER! 0_0

Answer (score 3):

When you use margin:auto you must also specify a width. I think you are trying to center the contents of the body with a background #E8E8E8. Do this instead

```
body {
    margin:auto;
    padding: 0;
    font: 12px/1.4 Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #000000;
    width: 1020px; //or anything else you want
    background:#E8E8E8;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant center anything that has no width, or is the parent-div with 100% because it cant relate to anything.

If you are going to use your body you need something like this:

```
body{
    width:980px;
    height:100%:
}
```

what most people do is using a container or wrapper. That gives you bit more control.

```
.container{
    width:980px;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
}
```

as you can see I gave the container as classs and a position:relative. This allows you to use it multiple times on the same page.

Answer (score -1):

You need to center div itself, something like this:

```
div.page {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```